# if f preserves angle at $z_0$ with some condition, is f holomorphic at$z_0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f:\Omega\to C$ is a complex valued function, real differentiable at $z_0\in\Omega$ and $J_f(z_0)\not=0$

then if $f$ preserves angle at $z_0$ is $f$ is holomorphic at $z_0$ with $f'(z_0)\not=0$?

i proved converse of this statement but cannot prove this.. i would really appreciate any help, hints

Comment: @Mon I think there is a nice detailed discussion about this in the book by Ahlfors

Comment: @happymath what is the title of the book?

Comment: Ahlfors Complex analysis edition 1 to 3  chapter 3 analytic functions as mappings

Comment: Nehari  Conformal mapping 1952 (Dover 1975)

Comment: You also need that $f'(z_0)$ preserves the orientation. The map $z\to \bar z$ is not holomorphic. A preserving orientation linear map from $\bf R^2$ to $\bf R^2$ is a similitude, therefore $\bf C$ linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is : Yes. for a detailled explaination see

Ahlfors Complex analysis edition 1 to 3 chapter 3: analytic functions as mappings
or Nehari conformal mapping Chapter 5 page 150

if $f'(z_0)=f''(z_0)=\ldots=f^{(n-1)}=0$ and $f^{(n)}(z_0) \neq 0$ then the angles are magnified by n in $z_0$.

Comment: Isn't $f(x+iy)=x-iy$ a contradiction. I think as Thomas pointed out it should preserve orientation as well